# Why does this use of function outside evaluate crashes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello here is the MWE :

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{math} % Pour evaluate

    \def\FTUn(#1){1/( W*(#1-sqrt((#1*#1) -1)))}
    \def\FTDeux(#1){1/(W *(#1+sqrt((#1*#1) -1)))}
    \def\FSupAUn(#1,#2){ \Kg * (1 - ( 1/( #1 - #2 ) )*( #1 *exp(-x/ #1 ) - #2 *exp(-x/ #2 ) ))   }

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[  declare function={ W=pi*2;  }]
            \def\Kg{2}
            \def\Ezero{1}
            \def\Ttrace{3}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot[thick=3pt,ultra thick,domain=0:(1/10),samples=50,
                evaluate={  \Tun = \FTUn(2) ;
                                \Tdeux =  \FTDeux(2); }
                ] {  \FSupAUn(\Tun, \Tdeux)  };
        %       ] {  \FSupAUn( \FTUn(2) , \FTDeux(2) )  };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This works fine but use the commented instead of the one above and you get :

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
```

Comment: The usual trick: use `{}`'s: `{\FTUn(2)}`, etc. Otherwise it does not know it needs to evalute them. Btw why don't you just declare them as functions?

Comment: Thanks, you're the man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other places in tikz we need braces to tell it to evaluate a function.

So use

```
{\FTUn(2)}
```

etc.

(As Thorbjørn mentions in the comments, the whole issue is probably the `()` confusing the TikZ argument parser. It is just a good thing to remember that adding `{}` to calculations often helps if you run into problems)

Comment: Isn't it rather that the parentheses in the function call confuses the parser? That is, it sees a `(`, and expects a `(x,y)` coordinate, so it finds the first `)`  and takes that as the end of the coordinate.

Comment: @TorbjørnT probably, this is just easier to understand for laypeople